# Array to String in Swift, stringInterpolationSegment

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert an array of enums to a string in Swift.  My enum is Printable and has a description property.

I thought this would work:

```
", ".join(a.map { String($0) })
```

but the compiler complains

```
Missing argument label 'stringInterpolationSegment:' in call
```

So, I follow the suggestion,

```
", ".join(a.map { String(stringInterpolationSegment: $0) })
```

But I do not understand:

1. Why is the argument label needed?
2. What is the type of stringInterpolationSegment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a `String` initializer with your enum type because there isn't an initializer that takes that type.

There are a number of initializers for `String` that have the `stringInterpolationSegment` argument and they each implement it for a different type.  The types include `Bool`, `Float`, `Int`, and `Character` among others.  When all else fails, there is a generic fallback:

```
/// Create an instance containing `expr`\ 's `print` representation
init<T>(stringInterpolationSegment expr: T)
```

This is the version that is being called for your enum since it isn't one of the supported types.

Note, you can also do the following which is more succinct:

```
", ".join(a.map { toString($0) })
```

and you can skip the closure expression (thanks for pointing that out @Airspeed Velocity):

```
", ".join(a.map(toString))
```

Comment: You can skip the closure expression: `", ".join(a.map(toString))`.

Answer (score 1):

As @vacawama points out, the error message is a bit of a red herring, and you can use `map` and `toString` to convert it.

But what’s nice is, if you’ve already implemented `Printable`, then the array’s implementation of `Printable` will also use it, so you can just do `toString(a)` to get a similar output.

Comment: The OP said his enum is Printable and has a description property.

Comment: oops missed that my bad!

Comment: This works nicely if you don't mind the enclosing brackets `[` and `]`.

Comment: `dropLast(dropFirst(toString(a)))` (kidding)